# How to plot a multicolum file in gnuplot

Tags: colors, gnuplot

I am having a multicoulum file and after certain rows it has a row break. 
It looks like

```
 # SET:   1
   0.00000 -62.49368   0.07000
   0.00639 -62.49367   0.07000
   0.01276 -62.49367   0.07000
   0.01914 -62.49366   0.07000
   0.02553 -62.49365   0.07000
   0.03190 -62.49364   0.07000
   0.03829 -62.49362   0.07000
   0.04467 -62.49361   0.07000
   0.05106 -62.49359   0.07000
   0.05743 -62.49356   0.07000

 # SET:   2
   0.00000 -62.49342   0.07000
   0.00639 -62.49342   0.07000
   0.01276 -62.49341   0.07000
   0.01914 -62.49340   0.07000
   0.02553 -62.49339   0.07000
   0.03190 -62.49338   0.07000
   0.03829 -62.49337   0.07000
   0.04467 -62.49335   0.07000

 # SET:   3
   0.00000 -62.47334   0.07000
   0.00639 -62.47225   0.07000
   0.01276 -62.47228   0.07000
   0.01914 -62.47231   0.07000
   0.02553 -62.47236   0.07000
   0.03190 -62.47242   0.07000
   0.03829 -62.47248   0.07000
   0.04467 -62.47256   0.07000
   0.05106 -62.47264   0.07000
   0.05743 -62.47273   0.07000
   0.06381 -62.47283   0.07000
   0.07020 -62.47296   0.07000
   0.07657 -62.47296   0.07000
```

and so on.

My plot is produced using

```
plot 'data' u 1:2 w l lc 2
```

The y-axis data are around zero from some negative to positive scale alining along x-axis.
I want to make top line just below the zero and just above the zero (horizontal line at Y=0 at) with different colour.

The data set which is to be plotted near to Y=0 (along x-axis) from data file looks like ($2 will flip the sign from negative to positive)

```
 # SET:  38
   0.00000  -0.88752   0.07000
   0.00639  -0.88731   0.07000
   0.01276  -0.88751   0.07000
   0.01914  -0.88783   0.07000
   0.02553  -0.88827   0.07000
   0.03190  -0.88884   0.07000
   0.03829  -0.88954   0.07000
   0.04467  -0.89036   0.07000
   0.05106  -0.89132   0.07000
   0.05743  -0.89240   0.07000

 # SET:  39
   0.00000   2.02394   0.07000
   0.00639   2.02456   0.07000
   0.01276   2.02642   0.07000
   0.01914   2.02950   0.07000
   0.02553   2.03379   0.07000
   0.03190   2.03927   0.07000
   0.03829   2.04590   0.07000
   0.04467   2.05364   0.07000
   0.05106   2.06264   0.07000
   0.05743   2.07248   0.07000
   0.06381   2.08330   0.07000
   0.07020   2.09494   0.07000
   0.07657   2.10755   0.07000
```

So basically I want to make the both the lines colorful which changes the sign at colum 2 from negative to positive. The line can be grepped using awk and grep commands and can be seen that after which SET $2 changes from negative to positive and then that SET index can be used in gnuplot to make the line colorful. 
Unfortunately I do not know how to do it.
Hope I have explained it nicely. Please let me know if I need to clarify it more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to have the line in one color (e.g. red `0xff0000`) when the value in column 2 is smaller zero and and another color (e.g. green `0x00ff00`) if it is larger zero. Simply define a function which returns a color code in the form of `0xRRGGBB`.

Maybe something like this?

(If you are plotting from file skip the part `$Data <<EOD ... EOD` and in the plot command replace `$Data` with your filename, e.g. `'MyFile.dat'`.

**Code:**

```
### color dependent on column value
reset session  
$Data <<EOD
 # SET:  38
   0.00000  -0.88752   0.07000
   0.00639  -0.88731   0.07000
   0.01276  -0.88751   0.07000
   0.01914  -0.88783   0.07000
   0.02553  -0.88827   0.07000
   0.03190  -0.88884   0.07000
   0.03829  -0.88954   0.07000
   0.04467  -0.89036   0.07000
   0.05106  -0.89132   0.07000
   0.05743  -0.89240   0.07000

 # SET:  39
   0.00000   2.02394   0.07000
   0.00639   2.02456   0.07000
   0.01276   2.02642   0.07000
   0.01914   2.02950   0.07000
   0.02553   2.03379   0.07000
   0.03190   2.03927   0.07000
   0.03829   2.04590   0.07000
   0.04467   2.05364   0.07000
   0.05106   2.06264   0.07000
   0.05743   2.07248   0.07000
   0.06381   2.08330   0.07000
   0.07020   2.09494   0.07000
   0.07657   2.10755   0.07000
EOD

myColor(n) = n<0 ? 0xff0000 : 0x00ff00
plot $Data u 1:2:(myColor($2)) w lp pt 7 lc rgb var notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

After clarification in the comments the following might be a possible solution.

You plot your data into a dummy table and check which is the last set which has column2-values smaller than zero. `column(-1)` contains the number of the set (counting starts from zero). Check also `help pseudocolumns`. 
You modify your color function a bit and take the colors from an array.
Tested with gnuplot 5.2.6.

**Code:**

```
### color dependent on column value
reset session

# create some random test data
set print $Data
Sets = 30
GapPos = int(rand(0)*Sets/3)+Sets/3
GapSize = 3
f(x) = (x-GapPos)+rand(0)*0.5 + (x>=GapPos ? GapSize : 0)
do for [i=1:Sets] {
    print "# SET:  ".i
    do for [j=1:10] {
        print sprintf("%.4f %.4f", (j+rand(0))/10., f(i))
    }
    print "\n"
}
set print

# find the SET-no. where column 2 values change from negative to positive
set table $Dummy
    plot $Data u (SetNo = $2<0 ? column(-1)+1 : SetNo) with table
unset table

# set the colors
array ArrColors[6] = [0xff0000, 0x00ff00, 0x0000ff, 0xff00ff, 0xffff00, 0x00ffff]
myColor(n) = n<SetNo-3 || n>=SetNo+3? 0xcccccc : ArrColors[n-SetNo+4]

plot $Data u 1:2:(myColor(column(-1))) w lp pt 7 lc rgb var notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Dear Theozh, It worked for me but this plots all the lines above zero in green while below zero it plots in red. I want only one (or maximum three) line around zero to be in different colour and rest lines on both side in same clour.

Comment: do you mean in your case e.g. SET 1 to 37 plotted in grey, SET 38 in green, SET 39 in red, and SET 40 to the rest again in grey?

Comment: No, I mean 1 to 37 are in Red while 38 to all above in green. I need very few (max 3 around zero, i.e. 37, 36 and 35 in a different colour and then 38, 39, 40 in different colour and rest all (below zero or above can be in a single colour).

Comment: sorry, it's still not clear to me. Let me try again: 1 to 34 in Color1, 35 in Color2, 36 in Color3, 37 in Color4, 38 in Color5, 39 in Color6, 40 in Color7 and 41 to x in Color1 again? Whereby Set38 is the last set with Column2_value<0 and Set39 is the first set with Column2_value>0?

Comment: Exactly,  what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks you very much Theozh